# Не могу понять в чём ошибка?

Tags: javascript

Задача:

Напишите последовательность команд, вычисляющих количество часов, минут и секунд в данном количестве суток.

1. Создайте переменную days и присвойте ей значение произвольного числа от 1 до 364.
2. Создайте переменную hours и присвойте ей значение выражения для нахождения количества часов.
3. Создайте переменную minutes и присвойте ей значение выражения для нахождения количества минут.
4. Создайте переменную seconds и присвойте ей значение выражения для нахождения количества секунд.

Пример:

```
const weeks = 3; const days = weeks * 7;
```

Моё решение:

```
const days = 3; const hours = days * 24; const minutes = days * 1440; const seconds = days * 259200;
```

Прописывает ошибку. Не могу понять почему?

В вашем решении есть ошибки

```
PassПеременная `days` существует и имеет значение
PassПеременная `days` является числом
PassПеременная `days` не является NaN
PassПеременная `days` принадлежит интервалу от 1 до 364
PassПеременная `hours` существует и имеет значение
PassПеременная `hours` является числом
PassПеременная `hours` не является NaN
PassПеременная `hours` вычислена верно
PassПеременная `minutes` существует и имеет значение
PassПеременная `minutes` является числом
PassПеременная `minutes` не является NaN
PassПеременная `minutes` вычислена верно
PassПеременная `seconds` существует и имеет значение
PassПеременная `seconds` является числом
PassПеременная `seconds` не является NaN
FailПеременная `seconds` вычислена верно
expected 777600 to equal 259200
```

Comment: Обращаю внимание на последнюю строку: `FailПеременная seconds вычислена верно expected 777600 to equal 259200`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В сутках 86400 секунд а вы указываете 259200( сумма 3х суток )

```
const seconds = days * 86400;
```

Comment: Исправил. Действительно ошибка была именно в этом const seconds = days * 86400 Огромное спасибо за помощь!!!!!)

Comment: В следующий раз будьте внимательнее =)

Answer (score 0):

В часе 60 минут, поэтому чтобы вычислить количество минут:
`const minutes = hours * 60`

Comment: Попробовал применить const minutes = hours * 60 , но ошибка всё та же: FailПеременная `seconds` вычислена верно
expected 777600 to equal 259200

Comment: А что насчёт следующих? Вы же не применили к другим переменным подобный подход: `const seconds = minutes * 60;`

Comment: Уже всё исправил) const days = 3;
const hours = days * 24;
const minutes = hours * 60;
const seconds = days * 86400;

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
const days = 3
const hours = days * 24
const minutes = days * 24 * 60
const seconds = days * 24 * 60 * 60
```